# What is the font used in this letterhead?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can anybody tell the name of the font used to write the business name?

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions and tell us what you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

[image]That would be:  **ITC Benguiat Std Condensed Medium (by ITC)**